# Lists all employees who reside in a state that is different from the state their company's headquarter is located in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on three SQL table and try to get all the employees whose companies are not in the same state as their company head quarters  as follows

Table: **Employee**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ EmployeeID ║ FirstName ║ LastName  ║ Birthdate ║ HomeState ║ Gender ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║          1 ║ John      ║ Doe       ║ 1/1/1978  ║ FL        ║ M      ║
║          2 ║ Jane      ║ Eyre      ║ 4/7/1985  ║ AL        ║ F      ║
║          3 ║ Alexander ║ Hamilton  ║ 6/4/1960  ║ NY        ║ M      ║
║          4 ║ Chris     ║ Smith     ║ 12/5/1990 ║ CA        ║ M      ║
║          5 ║ Emily     ║ Dickinson ║ 3/5/1945  ║ VT        ║ F      ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════╝
```

Table: Company

```
CompanyID   CompanyName               HQState
1          Steve's Widgets Inc         FL
2         Spigots and More LLC         NY
3         Maria's Bakery               CA
```

Table: Employment

```
EmploymentID   CompanyID   EmployeeID   EmploymentStartDate   EmploymentEndDate
1                     1      1             1/1/2000                NULL
2                     1      2            4/1/2019               5/1/2015
3                     1      3              5/1/2015                NULL
4                     2      4               3/6/2009            7/1/2015
5                     3       5            2/1/2002             NULL
```

From the above tables I'm trying to retrieve first and last names of all employees who reside in a state different from the state of their company

How to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with JOINs?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: No. Not much on joins

Comment: Is someone still an employee if they have an EmploymentEndDate populated?

Comment: I think you should read / watch / attend basic SQL tutorial / training, instead of asking the most basic things here as a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT
    Employee.FirstName
    , Employee.LastName
FROM
    Employee INNER JOIN
    Employment ON Employee.EmployeeId = Employment.EmployeeId INNER JOIN
    Company ON Employment.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
WHERE
    Employee.HomeState <> Company.HQState
```

@xQbert makes a good point about employment period.  This would only count those who are "currently" employed (based on today's date):

```
SELECT
    Employee.FirstName
    , Employee.LastName
FROM
    Employee INNER JOIN
    Employment ON Employee.EmployeeId = Employment.EmployeeId INNER JOIN
    Company ON Employment.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
WHERE
    Employee.HomeState <> Company.HQState
AND Employment.StartDate <= GETDATE()
AND (Employement.EndDate IS NULL OR Employment.EndDate >= GETDATE())
```

Comment: Consider: Is someone still an employee if they have an EmploymentEndDate populated? where... `and Employment.EmploymentEndDate is null and Employment.EmploymentStartDate>= getdate()`